# How to use WoWLAN with linux

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, wake-on-lan

I just bought an PCI-e WIFI/Bluetooth card to upgrade my PC. The chip is an Intel AX200 and supposedly supports Wake on Wireless LAN (WoWLAN). However I could not find any guide on how to setup WoWLAN on unix. Most tutorials discuss only the LAN case. the commands used there don't work. For example the first part in https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Wake-on-LAN to enable `ethtool interface | grep Wake-on` which does not work on my wireless interface `wlp34s0`

Can somebody please provide me some help or links?

Answer (score 1):

Use `iw` to control Wake-on-WLAN.

```
iw phy0 wowlan show
iw phy0 wowlan enable magic-packet
```